# Method return type in build.gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a method in build.gradle that basically creates an oracle database connection and returns it. But while running the script, it shows build failed as seen in the screenshot below.

```
def ext.getOracleConnection = { ->
            java.sql.Connection conn = null;
            try{
                configurations.jdbcdriver.files.each {
                    groovy.sql.Sql.classLoader.addURL(it.toURI().toURL())
                }   
                configurations.xdb.files.each {
                    groovy.sql.Sql.classLoader.addURL(it.toURI().toURL())
                }
                //load the jdbc driver and create the connection.
                java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(groovy.sql.Sql.classLoader.loadClass("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance())
                readProperites();
                conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, dbUser, dbPassword);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return conn;
        }
```

[image]

I tried changing the return type to java.sql.Connection but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a solution?.

Comment: next time please add the text of the exception instead of a screenshot.  your screenshot can not be searched (time will heal this maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compilation error as shown in the failure message.

You need to remove `def` from the declaration.